# Firebase dynamic link to open specific activity with data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm facing some problems with implementing Firebase Dynamic links in my app.

My app contains a gallery of books and under each book, there is a share button. When a user clicks that button it creates a message that he can send other uses saying something like: "Hey you might like this book, check it here!"

Once the user clicks the image, I had like it to open the app at that activity (called BookDetailActivity). If the user has the app, I had like it to open BookDetailActivity with the specific intent data that is relevant to that book (say bookid = abcde) and if the user doesn't have the app, to send him to download the app.

In order to do so, I added to my manifest the following code under BookDetailActivity:

```
<activity android:name=".BookDetailActivity">
    <intent-filter android:label="SB">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="https://x.y.link"
            android:pathPrefix="/SB"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then, inside the BookDetailActivity, I added the following (used it just to check if the app opens at that activity and to see the link I get).

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
        .getDynamicLink( getIntent() )
        .addOnSuccessListener( this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                Uri deepLink = null;
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                    Log.d( "TEST1", deepLink + "" );
                }
            }
        } )
        .addOnFailureListener( this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d( "TEST2", "HERE" );
            }
        } );
```

Now, the button that sends that invitation message is:

```
ib_Share.setOnClickListener( v -> {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_SEND );

    String suggest = "Hey you might like this book, check it here! - https://x.y.link/SB?bookid=abcde";
    shareIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml( suggest ) );
    shareIntent.setType( "text/html" );
    startActivity( shareIntent );
} );
```

What I get is that I successfully send the message to another user, the user clicks on that link and the app opens but at the MAIN ACTIVITY instead of at BookDetail activity.

Is there a reason it won't take the user to that correct activity?

The way it looks in my Firebase Console is( the domain (x.y.link is just an example):

[image]

Also, how users that have a previous version of my app without the `FirebaseDynamicLinks` part in their BookDetailActivity code will manage to get these invitations? It will open them to download the app or just do nothing?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I guess, whenever dynamic links are clicked, it opens your `MainActivity`. I tried to arrive at the solution as below.

In your `MainActivity`, check if there is any new intent created because of the dynamic link using `onNewIntent()` method

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent ( Intent newIntent ) {
   super.onNewIntent ( newIntent );
   setIntent ( newIntent );
   checkDynamicLinkIntent ();
}

private void checkDynamicLinkIntent () {
   if (!Objects.equals ( null, getIntent ().getData () )) {
       Uri dynamicLink = Uri.parse ( getIntent ().getData ().toString () );
       parameterValue = dynamicLink.getQueryParameter ( parameterName );
       //get any data from your URI if needed
       Intent intent = new Intent ( MainActivity.this, BookDetailActivity.class );
       intent.putExtra ( "bookDetail", parameterValue );
       startActivity ( intent );
    }
}
```

Hope the above code snippet helps you! :)